# Is traversing an unconnected graph possible?

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs

I have been assigned a fun project: design and implement a program that maintains the data of a simple social network. Each person in the network should have a profile that contains his name, current status, and a friends list.

I think it is clear that the project calls for the use of the ADT graph. Each vertex represents a person in the network and an edge between vertices a friendship. Now, the graph may not be connected because some members do not have any friends in the network. With that in mind, consider this feature that must be implemented:

**•The network must have a feature that computes the “emergency phone chain," make sure that each member in the network is contacted, and only by one person. Any of the people in the network may initiate the first call. Utilize a depth-first graph traversal algorithm.**

Now, what I think my professor is suggesting is merely a full traversal of the graph. How is that possible for an unconnected graph? Any suggestions?

(btw, the wording above is somewhat unclear - does the professor mean that everyone in the network is contact by the same one person? Thoughts? I would ask her, but she is unavailable until next week.)

Answer (score 1):

That's a question only your professor can answer. There are at least two possible solutions:

1. Each "chain" involves a single connected component.
2. Some links will be among non-friends.

In the latter case, you would like to minimize the number of unfriendly links. If there are $c$ connected components, then you only need $c-1$ of these.